# Pass Varnish backend response to solr

Tags: command-line, solr, hook, varnish

does anybody know if there is an option to combine varnish with Solr.

What I'd like to do is:

1. User requests a URL
2. Varnish hasn't a cached version or just an outdated version
3. Varnish calls the backend and finally receivs the response

This is the point where I'd like to hook into and pass the backend response to "./bin/solr post ..." so my solr index will immediately be updated every time I deliver a new content version.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Boris

Comment: Solr is one of the fastest product I have ever seen and you want put a web cache in front of it. Why do you want do this?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. keep muy cache punto date 2. keep muy solr up to date. Booth without querrying multiple Times.

Comment: Just update data in Solr. You can update even millions of documents without have performance loss.

Comment: I dont want to cache solr. What I want is to fill my solr index every time the varnish needs to fetch from backend. This way the solr index would be uptodate with the published content and I don't need to make two queries. Respective I can't control what a crawler would load first.

Answer (score 0):

This is a twofold issue - one, sticking Varnish in front of Solr works as you'd expect. It takes the load away from Solr and allows Varnish to return content without having to query Solr.

However, you should keep your indexing process separate from the Varnish pipeline, otherwise you could have a very bad time if multiple threads start asking for an indexing process to be started within a short period of time. The proper way of doing this is to have a sensible time to live for responses in Varnish, use expire (through a ban or something similar in Varnish, or by attaching a index version identifier in your request to Solr), but launch and perform indexing outside of varnish' delivery of documents.

When the indexing completes you issue a ban to Varnish that tells Varnish that any existing, cached responses are invalid - this makes Varnish start querying your backend again. This way Varnish can do what it's great for, caching content, and you can keep the logic that decides when to update your index and when an update is necessary outside of Varnish.

And while Solr does effective caching, Varnish does a far better job (as it can consider only the response and not have to look at anything further behind in the chain) and can thus alleviate the load from repetitive queries.